# MIPS find end of string

Tags: mips32

I have the following mips code (running it in QTSPIM), that is supposed to count the number of characters in a string and print them.

The logic behind it is very simple but is does not work as it should. Everything goes well until it reaches the end of the string and then it continues counting even though I compare each element to $zero to find the end of string (\0).

Is there something wrong with my condition to exit the loop, or *my_string* does not contain \0 in the end so it won't exit?

```
    .data
endl: .asciiz "\n"
my_string: .asciiz "thisisastring"
star: .asciiz "*"
str_end: .word 0
space: .asciiz " "

    .text
    .globl main

main:
    la $a0, my_string
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, endl
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $t0, my_string   #   load mystring to $t0
    li $t1, 0           #   make $t1 = 0, character counter
    lb $t2, ($t0)       #   make $t2 point to the first character of "my_string"
    li $t3, 1           #   $t3 is the ++ register to go to the next character  
    li $t4, 0           #   character counter
    la $t5, str_end

cont:
    beqz $t0, print #   if \0 is found print and exit
    addi $t4, $t4, 1        #   increase the counter

    lbu $a0, ($t0)          #   print current character
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    addi $t0, $t0, 1        #   go to next char
    #move $t2, $t0


    j cont

print:
    move $a0, $t4
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    j exit

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the order of the instructions, the logic of the code.

Here is the corrected version with no redundant code:

```
    .data
endl: .asciiz "\n"
my_string: .asciiz "thisisastring"
str_end: .word 0

    .text
    .globl main

main:
    la $a0, my_string
    li $v0, 4           #   print the string
    syscall

    la $a0, endl        #   print endl
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $t0, my_string   #   load mystring to $t0
    li $t1, 0           #   make $t1 = 0, character counter
    lb $t2, 0($t0)      #   make $t2 point to the first character of "my_string"
    la $t5, str_end

cont:
    lb $a0, 0($t0)          #   print current character
    beqz $a0, print         #   if \0 is found print and exit

    addi $t1, $t1, 1        #   increase the counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1        #   go to next char

    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    j cont


print:
    move $a0, $t1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    j exit

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```